# Unable to find font cache of matplotlib on a mac

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I've researched this a lot and can't get it to work.

How can I change the font for matplotlib?

I think my issue is the font cache, based on my research.

I have the ttf in the right folder.

people keep saying 
rm ~/.matplotlib/fontList.cache

is the command to use, but I can't find a .matplotlib folder or a fontlist.cache anywhere on my computer.

I'm using a Mac.
Do I need to provide more information or does it seem like it might just be the cache?
If it's the cache, how do I clear it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

run the following code to get the font cache dir:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_cachedir()
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [matplotlib.font_manager](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html)

> A module for finding, managing, and using fonts across platforms.