# import matplotlib.pyplot - fc-list hangs

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, osx-yosemite

I am experiencing the same problem as described in [import matplotlib.pyplot hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490444/import-matplotlib-pyplot-hangs) after updating my matplotlib version `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` hangs while executing `fc-list`.

However, [the proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24982107/2043505) does not work for me; running `fc-list` in `~/.matplotlib` takes 100% CPU and does not finish within 15 minutes.

I have the following configuration:

- Mac, running OS 10.10.5 (OS X Yosemite)
- Python 2.7.5
- matplotlib 1.4.3 (was 1.3.1, no problems with that version)

To update my matplotlib version, I used:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

If I re-run this command now, I get

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): matplotlib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing!=2.0.0,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nose>=0.11.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mock in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): funcsigs in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from mock->matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr>=0.11 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from mock->matplotlib)
```

and `sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib`:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyparsing!=2.0.0,>=1.5.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: nose>=0.11.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: mock in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: funcsigs in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from mock->matplotlib)
Requirement already up-to-date: pbr>=0.11 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from mock->matplotlib)
```

I have a `fontList.cache` file in `~/.matplotlib`. This file is old (dating back to 2013, thus older than this update attempt).

Questions:

1. Despite the `fontList.cache` file, should I run `fc-list`, expecting it to finish at some point?
2. Is matplotlib expecting to find the `fontList.cache` file in a different location? Maybe my install/update of matplotlib messed up some path - but: [`matplotlib.get_cachedir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196416/2043505) returns `/Users/MyName/.matplotlib`
3. Has the filename changed? Should I rename `fontList.cache`?
4. I do not have the `/usr/X11/lin`directory anymore. However, could `fc-list` still enter an infinite loop [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17497298/2043505)?

Comment: Given that I cannot reproduce my own problem, I leave it to the community to VtC if we feel that the Q/A pair here would not help future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem after posting the question.

---

I suspect that (re-)running

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

and/or

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

while writing the question (to capture the on-screen output) fixed the previously existing issue.

`fc-list` now finished within 2 minutes; hough it did not create a new `fontList.cache` file.

---

I can now call `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` as before.

Comment: I also ran into this problem, but merely waiting resulted in the program eventually terminating. And then on a second execution it worked quickly. I think it was building some kind of font cache that only needed to be done once.